# Jest SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jestjs

When I want to run my project with the command `npm run test`, I get the error below. What is causing this?

```
FAIL
● Test suite failed to run

SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins at Window.get localStorage [as localStorage] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:257:15)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: How do you access your application?.. I mean, Are you accessing it like, `http://localhost:port...` ?

Comment: This is problem with test runner, @DavidR, He has issue with >>>npm run test<<<

Comment: @MartinChaov Yup I know that. I would like see his reply in order to check if something wrong in his `jest` config :-)

Comment: I just started running into this myself... I'm not using local-storage at all in the code. Is your code using ts-jest as well?

Comment: @k2snowman69 Please check my answer and post your comment.

Comment: To give some context on this error, I started seeing it while attempting to update my `jest` version from `^22.3.0` to `^23.5.0` along with Babel 7.

Comment: I get this issue but fix with downgrade some dependencies.

Comment: Same issue when upgrading Jest from `27.5.1` to `29.5.0`

Answer (score 165):

In case, if you are accessing your application with a `http://localhost` prefix, you need to update your jest configuration (in your `jest.config.js`) as,

```
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/"
  }
```

In case you do not already have any jest configuration, just include the configuration in your `package.json`. For example:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  ...
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/"
  }
}
```

or in `jest.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  ...
}
```

or if you have `projects` configured:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  
  projects: [{
    runner: 'jest-runner',
    testURL: "http://localhost/",

    // ...
  }]
}
```

for configuration in `package.json`, testURL is removed in jest v28. Now you should use testEnvironmentOptions to pass url option like that:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
        "url": "http://localhost/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep this worked for me... though I don't quite understand why I need this nor why it was working before the latest upgrade

Comment: This is discussed in the `jest` github page: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6766

Comment: You can also use the cli option in your npm script : `jest --testURL=\"http://localhost\"`. Useful if you cannot set a global jest configuration because of another environment (react-scripts for me).

Comment: I am working on react native. Even for me `testUrl` worked.

Answer (score 83):

I just had this cropping up in a large monorepo (in unit tests, that otherwise wouldn't have required jsdom). Explicitly setting the following in our `jest.config.js` (or the `package.json` equivalent) also alleviated that issue:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node'
}
```

Update: As Nicolas mentioned below (thanks!), you can also add the following flags if you're not using any config files:

```
jest --testEnvironment node    
# or 
jest --env=node
```

Comment: This worked for me! THIS is the answer you need! Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the author hasn`t a node environment - in his case he should set testEnvironment: "jsdom". This works for me with the latest update. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: As mentioned in some other answers below, you can skip the generation of a config file (or package.json property) by running `jest --testEnvironment node` or its shorthand `jest --env=node`, intead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It seems more appropriate for the error. Also if you are only testing scripts it makes no sense to define a `testURL`.

Answer (score 21):

You must specify what environment (`--env`) are you going to use.

When you run `jest` command in the `package.json` you should specify the environment (`jsdom` or `node`). For example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "jest": "jest --env=node --colors --coverage test",
    "test": "npm run jest"
  },
```

This should work for you!

Comment: If you're using jsdom, the same thing happens regardless of whether or not you specify an `env` via config or commandline. This only started happening with jest's latest update today. Please see @David R's answer for a solution if this is the case for you.

Comment: It makes sense, the environment determines how the test should run and jsdom seems to be the default.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using jsdom, make sure you include url.

Checkout jsdom repository simple options. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#simple-options

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM(`...`, { url: "https://example.org/" });
```

Comment: In my case my i added that code in my jsdom configuration file. ```var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const {document }  = (new JSDOM('',{ url: "https://localhost/",})).window;

global.document = document;```

Comment: +1 While not specifically about Jest, this is an alternative solution and could be used for other setups (since this is the top SO for the error code, others, like me, will find this page who aren't using Jest)  Per @dspacejs good question, this would be a separate file that's called via your test command in `package.json`.  For example, this code could be saved in a `testHelper.ts` file and called using mocha: `scripts: { test-setup: 'mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-nocde/register --require testHelper.ts --reporter progress' }`.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and manually installing `jest-environment-jsdom` version 28 (based on [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2304#issuecomment-1145594493)) solved it.

Comment: To make this work, I had to install `jest-environment-jsdom` at the same version as `jest` using Yarn `resolutions`.

Answer (score 8):

The issue for me occured when I updated the jest to v28.0.3.
Seems like in the release 28.0.0 they depricated the testUrl and introduced an object testEnvironmentOptions with property url that has default value 'http://localhost/'.

> Deprecation Warning:
>
> Option "testURL" was replaced by passing the URL via
> "testEnvironmentOptions.url".
>
> Please update your configuration.
>
> Configuration Documentation:   https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Check the PR here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/10797

However my issue disapeared when I updated the jest-environment-jsdom and set in the jest.config.js the testEnvironment to it.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Setting "testEnvironmentOptions.url" did not work for me. But installing "jest-environment-jsdom" and updating the property "testEnvironment" as you said worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: To get this one to work, I had to install `jest-environment-jsdom`: `yarn add --dev jest-environment-jsdom`.

Answer (score 5):

The suggestion in the top-rated answer of adding `testURL: "http://localhost"` to my Jest config didn't work for me. However, [this suggestion from the jsdom GitHub discussion](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2304#issuecomment-408972393), of passing a URL in when creating the jsdom object, did.

```js
const url = 'http://localhost';

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>', { url });
```

Answer (score 3):

for me this was solved by upgrading to     "jest": "^24.9.0",

Answer (score 3):

To solve the `Jest SecurityError: localStorage` error you need to add the **`jest: { ... }`** part to your **package.json** file

```
{

"name": "...",
"version": "..",
"main": "..",
"description": "...",
...

"jest": { "verbose": true, "testURL": "http://localhost/" },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but for me, the problem was caused because I had mistakenly installed random packages with `npm update`. I was running `npm install` and then `npm update` but I should have only ran `npm install`.  I fixed the problem by deleting `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` again.

Comment: This relates to me, I actually wasn't able to finish `npm install` properly due to enterprise proxy. So, the pattern would be uncompleted `npm install`ation

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything while working with React JS. It is default behavior of the create-react-app to place JEST and setting up testing environment.
On running of below,it start showing the test success or fail,

> npm test

In case you want test coverage, you simply need to add below to package.json file

> "test": "react-scripts test --coverage"
>   Now your "script" of package.json look like,

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This popped up with me when integrating `enzyme` with `jest`. The [Github Issue Discussion](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2304#issuecomment-408329897) suggests the same as noted above, namely adding

```
"testURL": "http://localhost/"
```

to the jest config. However, it's good to know that this is triggered also by enzyme. For me it was React v15 and the v15 adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and placing this in my `package.json` file worked for me:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsdom you have to change your setup for tests like this:

````
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>', {
  url: 'http://localhost/',
});```
````