# SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins with new testEnvironmentOptions.url option

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I got an error **SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origin**.
I tried all advises about this problem:

- set `testURL: "http://localhost/"`,
- set `testEnvironmentOptions: { url: 'https://localhost/' }`.

All this in jest.config.js but it doesn't work for me.
My jest.config.js file:

````
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules",
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["mock-local-storage"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  verbose: true,
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
};```

Help me please
````

Comment: this looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554366/jest-securityerror-localstorage-is-not-available-for-opaque-origins

Answer (score 11):

These linked answers didn't work for me. This is the *only* thing that did: https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest28#jsdom

```
npm i --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
```

Curious how the error message lines up (it doesn't), but the new required dependency is definitely the issue on my end.